# How to compare hashmap key (country name) with country name retrieve from a CSV file?

Tags: java, javafx

I would like to seek some opinion or assistance regarding my code for a heatmap based on the number of Wuhan cases each country has, code as shown below.

Currently, I have stored all country coordinates in a hashmap, and I have scraped out data from https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/ where I stored the country name and number of cases in a CSV file.

I am trying to compare the names of the country from the CSV file with the country name (key) in the hashmap, such that if such country exists plot the "heat area" on the map. However, currently, when I am trying to do the comparing by using an if-else statement as shown in my codes. However, the issues I am facing is that if the csv file is missing 1 country and it doesn't match with the hashmap, the code will not run. Only when the csv file contain all country name and it matches with the hashmap then the code will display the application as shown below. How do I go about plotting the "heat area" when comparing the country names from the csv file and the hashmap ?

**CODE**

```
 @Override public void init() {

    //Input the coordinates of the country, based on the size of the javafx.
    //Limitation is the current coordinates are not the entire list of country in the world.
    HashMap<String, List<Integer>> countryCoordinates = new HashMap<>();
    Integer[] coordinates = {};
    countryCoordinates.put("China", Arrays.asList(700, 180));
    countryCoordinates.put("Diamond Princess", Arrays.asList(810, 170));
    countryCoordinates.put("Singapore", Arrays.asList(726, 310));
    countryCoordinates.put("Japan", Arrays.asList(810, 170));
    countryCoordinates.put("Hong Kong", Arrays.asList(755, 225));
    countryCoordinates.put("Thailand", Arrays.asList(720, 250));
    countryCoordinates.put("S. Korea", Arrays.asList(780, 170));
    countryCoordinates.put("Taiwan", Arrays.asList(775, 220));
    countryCoordinates.put("Malaysia", Arrays.asList(725, 300));
    countryCoordinates.put("Germany", Arrays.asList(440, 115));
    countryCoordinates.put("Vietnam", Arrays.asList(740, 260));
    .
    .
    .

    Reader reader;
    try {
        //Retrieving the data from WorldMap CSV
        reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\ICT1009_TESTFILE\\WorldMap.csv"));
        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(reader);
        String[] nextRecord;
        while((nextRecord = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
            String retrieveCountry = nextRecord[0];
            //Comparing the hashmap key with the country name retrieve from CSV file
            //If the names matches, plot the heat area
            List<Integer> coordinatesOfThisCountry = countryCoordinates.get(retrieveCountry);
            if (coordinatesOfThisCountry != null) {
                    events = new Point2D[] {
                            asPoint2D(countryCoordinates.get(retrieveCountry)),
                    };
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Comment: You iterate multiple times over the whole map, which lets me assume that you missed the purpose of the map completely. The for and while loops are nested in the wrong order. You should first loop over the content of the CSV file and then lovate matching entries in the map. But not by iterating over the whole map. You should use the key to find entries in the map. Otherwise it makes no sense to use a map here. The lines after "events =" seem totally strange to me. Why streaming the whole map and converting that multiple times?

Comment: Hmm can I ask what do you mean I iterate multiple times over the whole map ? The map you see is just a background image to represent the world map. So if the country name and the hashmap key value matches then it would plot the "heat dot" on the map. as shown in my if-else statement.

Comment: These statements are iterating over the whole map: "for()", ".values()", ".map()", ".toArray()". I never saw so many nested iterators in one block. If you present a whole executable example program your will possibly get better help.

Answer (score 3):

The outer loop must read the CSV file line by line, the inner loop must compare with the map. However, the purpose of a map is to find matching entries much quicker by a hash code lookup instead of for-loop. So only the outer loop remains:

```
while((nextRecord = csvReader.readNext()) != null) 
{
    String retrieveCountry = nextRecord[0];
    String retrieveCases = nextRecord[1];

    // Find the existing country in the map
    List<Integer> coordinatesOfThisCountry=countryCoordinates.get(retrieveCountry);

    if (coordinatesOfThisCountry!=null)
    {
        // found
        // TODO: plot the "heat area" 
    }
    else
    {
       // not found
    }
}
```

Comment: The purpose of the map, is to compare the hashmap key that is the country name with the country name retrieve from the csv file, e.g. if the CSV file contain the country "china" then plot the "heat area" on the map. Currently, the code you have provided is to check whether if the list is empty, which is flawed in my case, as if the CSV only contain one country "china" the map will still plot all of the "heat dot" on the map

Comment: Denise, your comment is not correct. My example loops over the CSV file and checks if the country is in the map. The the file contains only one country, then the loop is only executed one, so it plots either zero or one heat area. There is no code that does "check whether if the list is empty".

Comment: Okay, but when I tried implementing your code into mine, and I tested removing all countries and leave only china in the csv file and trying running the codes. The heatmap still shows all the "heat area" on the map rather than showing on the "heat area" on china. Hence I wrote that comment.

Comment: Then there is something wrong in your code. The loop that I showed runs exactly 1x for each row in the the CSV file. You may use an IDE with debugger to step through your code, then you see what's going on.

Comment: Hi Stefan, yup I realise my mistakes. Could you give my try/catch code a look ? Now I am able to plot only the country with the "heat dot" if the csv file only contain 1 country. However, when I input a csv file with multiple country it is still showing only plotting 1 "heat dot" on 1 country

Comment: I cannot analyze your problem without having the full source code. Anyway I think you should analyze it yourself by adding log messages or using a debugger. Learning programming means also learning debugging.